# i want to get a time 09.30 from a label, as hr = 09 and min = 30, possible?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Get the time from a label 09.30 , i want to get it as hr = 09 and min = 30 if the label time is 08.12 the corresponding values like hr = 08 & min = 12 , Is it Possible?

Comment: `let hr = "09.30".split(separator: ".").first!` and `let min = "09.30".split(separator: ".").last!`

Comment: is it possible to add the timeLbl.text.split(separator: ".").first!     (timeLbl.text = "09.30" the label  time will change )

Comment: @SruthiCSankar Label text wont be changed

Comment: @holex, why do you need to split same string twice instead of storing result in var, and then reusing?

Comment: `if let minStr = timeLbl.text?.split(separator: ".").first, let min = Int(minStr) {
            print(min)
        }
        if let secStr = timeLbl.text?.split(separator: ".").last, let sec = Int(secStr) {
            print(sec)
        }`

Comment: @user28434, because that is a comment of the raw concept, not a worked out / optimised / foolproof answer.

Comment: @SruthiCSankar your looked link doesn't match the scenario

Comment: @SruthiCSankar what do you want to do after getting this value? Increment it?

Comment: ok, thank you @holex

Comment: @RajeshKumarR  please write it as answer with Increment it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `hour` and `minutes`,

```
let title = timeLbl.text?.split(separator: ".")

if let hourString = title?.first, let hour = Int(hourString) {
    print(hourString)
    print(hour)
}

if let minutesString = title?.last, let minutes = Int(minutesString) {
    print(minutesString)
    print(minutes)
}
```

---

To set two line `title` for `label`,

```
let titleString = timeLbl.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "\n")
timeLbl?.numberOfLines = 0
timeLbl?.text = titleString
```

Comment: It looks like authors wants them as `String`s with initial `0` kept.

Comment: @user28434 Not sure. But updated to use `hourString` and `minutesString` incase that is intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
let splitedStr = timeLbl.text?.split(separator: ".")
if let minStr = splitedStr?.first, let min = Int(minStr),
    let secStr = splitedStr?.last, let sec = Int(secStr) {
    var totalSec = (min * 60) + sec
    totalSec += 1
    timeLbl.text = String(format: "%02d.%02d", (totalSec/60),(totalSec%60)  )
}
```

Comment: Is possible to get the time in timeLbl.text = 09.30 AM , ie if the value is 15.30 then in label as 15.30 PM???

Comment: @SruthiCSankar just check if min is greater than 12 and add AM or PM

Comment: @SruthiCSankar who told you to use houRString.first ?

Comment: @SruthiCSankar use let min = Int(houRString)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191635/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-sruthi-c-sankar).